# ActiveRecord query with group and average

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models in a Rails application: a `home` has many `speed_tests`.

Every `speed_test` has as attributes: `hostname` and `download`.

I want to group hostnames and display the average of the download.

First of all I filter by city:

```
sts = SpeedTest.joins(:home).where("homes.city": city)
```

I have a collection of `speed_tests`, now I want to group them by `hostname` and get the average of `download` for every hostname

```
result = sts.select("hostname, AVG(download) as avg_download").group(:hostname)
```

The results are as following:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<SpeedTest id: nil, hostname: "46.128.35.112.dynamic.cablesurf.de">]>
```

Why I can't see the column `avg_download`? Am I force to use the column speed_test id? I am not interested in this attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see it because that field is not part of your model, it's a virtual attribute. Anyway, it's present. Just call it. Try

```
result.map(&:avg_download)
```